# SQL - Selecting rows by timestamp and ID

Tags: sql, mariadb, groupwise-maximum

I'm working with a list of engagement scores for each company.

```
SELECT pel.companyProfileID, pel.engagementScore, pel.createTimestamp
FROM partnerEngagementLog pel
```

A snippet of results for one company:

[image]

I'm trying to produce a cohort analysis table with:

- A single row for each companyProfileID.
- Columns for each engagementScore by latest, second latest, etc.

The issue is that time between timestamps varies and I'm having trouble figuring out how to select properly. Put another way, what I need is columns for "last score per companyID", "second-to-last", "third-to-last", etc. that are based on absolute row positioning and not date range.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, still learning SQL on the side as I develop my business.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Follow the groupwise-max tag for similar cases.  Or see [_my blog_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max)